# How I can get an index value of a array inside a another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a array in this format

```
const Adicionais = [{
  ID: 0,
  Nome: 'Adiocinais Açai',
  MaxOpcoes: 3,
  Itens: [{
    Nome: 'Morango',
    Valor: 5.00,
    ID: 0,
  }, {
    Nome: 'Raspas de Chocolate',
    Valor: 5.00,
    ID: 1,
  }, {
    Nome: 'Biz de Chocolate',
    Valor: 5.00,
    ID: 2,
  }]
}]
```

I need to get the value of index **VALOR** inside the array **ITENS** and SUM the value of all items that I have an ID saved in another array of the items selected. I tried do this that form

```
const ValorAdicionas = ProdutoAdicionais.filter((item) =>  (item.Itens.filter((a) => (adicionaisChecked.includes(a.ID))).reduce((a, v) => a = a + v.Valor, 0)))
```

but does not work. The array `ProdutosAdicionais` have the value of array `Adicionais`, and the array `adicionaisChecked` have the ID of array `Itens`

Comment: whats the expected output?

Comment: the expected output is the sum of all indice **VALOR** of the element ID is inside that array **AdicionaisChecked**, example i have the ID of  Item Banana and Melon, i need the sum of  the indice **VALOR** of these items

Comment: There is no word "indice" in English. The closest I could think of is the plural of index, indices. But now I'm not sure if maybe you mean "property" or "key"... Please do update your question if either makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const adicionaisChecked=[1];
const ProdutoAdicionais = [{
  ID: 0,
  Nome: 'Adiocinais Açai',
  MaxOpcoes: 3,
  Itens: [{
    Nome: 'Morango',
    Valor: 5.00,
    ID: 0,
  }, {
    Nome: 'Raspas de Chocolate',
    Valor: 5.00,
    ID: 1,
  }, {
    Nome: 'Biz de Chocolate',
    Valor: 5.00,
    ID: 2,
  }]
}]


const valorAdicionas = ProdutoAdicionais.reduce((acc,item)=>{
 return acc.concat(item.Itens.filter(a=>adicionaisChecked.includes(a.ID)))
},[]).reduce((a,v)=>a+v.Valor,0);

console.log(valorAdicionas);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code helping you

```
const Adicionais = [{
  ID: 0,
  Nome: 'Adiocinais Açai',
  MaxOpcoes: 3,
  Itens: [{
    Nome: 'Morango',
    Valor: 5.00,
    ID: 0,
  }, {
    Nome: 'Raspas de Chocolate',
    Valor: 5.00,
    ID: 1,
  }, {
    Nome: 'Biz de Chocolate',
    Valor: 5.00,
    ID: 2,
  }]
}]
adicionaisChecked = [0,1]
Adicionais.map(o=>o.Itens.filter(v=>adicionaisChecked.indexOf(v.ID) != -1)).map(k=>k.reduce((sum, prev)=>sum + prev.Valor,0))
```